# "It is time now" or "It is now time"?

Tags: adverbs, adverb-position

> It is time **now**

or

> It is **now** time

Which of these expressions is grammatically correct?

Comment: Both are grammatically correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position of certain time adjuncts in English is very flexible. Assuming your sentence is standing alone, *now* fits in every position: *Now it is time. It now is time. It is now time. It is time now*.

The default position of a time adjunct is at the end of the clause, so bringing it forward from that position gives it greater emphasis. Compare:

> I played tennis yesterday.
>
> Yesterday I played tennis.

Note that *yesterday* fits only in these two positions, whereas frequency adjuncts such as *sometimes* fit in three places:

> Sometimes I play tennis.
>
> I sometimes play tennis.
>
> I play tennis sometimes.

As you see, the rules governing the position of adverbs in English are rather complex.