# Where to position adverbs

Tags: adverbs, writing-style, adverb-position

They may sound both correct but which one is more acceptable in standard written English?

> She is writing a letter **now**.

or

> She is **now** writing a letter.

Thanks

Comment: They are both correct and as josh61 pointed out, you can often place an adverb of time (today, tomorrow etc.) at the beginning of a sentence. But you are asking if one form is more acceptable than another, and this depends on context, meaning the author wishes to convey and personal preferences.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/121262/44619 is a well-thought out answer If you click on the "adverb-position" tag you'll find other helpful answers.

Comment: One of the differences between the sentences is that the first sentence indicates that she is writing a letter at this moment. It does mean that she is occupied in writing  but says nothing about the context, content of or reason for the letter. The second sentence form is usually used in context: for example "Mary was very disappointed by the response to her verbal complaint. She is now writing a letter." This does not, necessarily, mean that she is currently writing a letter but it does indicate a determination to do so soon.

Answer (score 1):

The positioning of *now* depends on what you want to stress in the sentence,

Another alternative is: *Now she is writing a letter*; here *Now* is the word you want to emphasise, unlike in your first sentence. Your  second  example is more neutral with respect to the adverb of time.